# Use of setCustomValidity in form requires two clicks for onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I am working on a form that makes use of the HTML5 form validation attribute `required` for various `text` and `radio` button fields. The form also has two sets of checkboxes, of which at least one checkbox must be checked.

In order to keep the user error feedback consistent I am using the `setCustomValidity` method to throw a native error bubble when the checkboxes are left unchecked. This all works fine, however, there is an issue with error feedback when the form is submitted and the `onsubmit` event is used to trap unchecked checkboxes. This issue doesn't arise when the `onclick` event is bound to the submit button instead, but I understand it is preferable to use `onsubmit`.

**Onclick test case (Click submit button and error bubble appears first time!)**
http://jsfiddle.net/Jimadine/bZe5e/

**Onsubmit test case (Click submit button - error bubble appears after second click)**
http://jsfiddle.net/Jimadine/2vLszqac/

Furthermore, from my testing of the onsubmit case, Firefox highlights the unchecked checkboxes after the first click of the submit button; this is indicated by a red glow around the checkboxes. Then after a second click the error bubble displays. In other modern browsers the first click displays no on-screen indication that the checkboxes were left unchecked; I presume this is how the UX side of HTML5 validation was implemented in these browsers and that Firefox chose to do things slightly differently.

My question is why does the onsubmit test case require two clicks and what is an appropriate way to rectify this so it behaves like the onclick test case? I'm guessing it has something to do with the submit event firing after the validation but I'm not sure how to correct my code.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you're setting setCustomValidity while form submit has already happened. You have to set them before the form is submitted, i.e when you're rendering the form.

Comment: Yes, you understand correctly. I've since found a blog post where someone else encountered a similar issue (http://goo.gl/eGks5b)
So how does one assign the validation rules when the form loads? Do you have any simple examples? It would be much neater if my custom checkbox validation fired in the same way as the radio and text controls that have the required attribute.

Comment: I've read all about doing setCustomValidity before submitting; however, there are cases when on submit is really what I need. (On click does not work with hitting enter.) Often the server will tell me which fields are bad and it can only do so when all of them are filled. (Cannot rely on last field being filled last either.) Just really with there was a hack to setCustomValidity on submit...

Comment: When tabbing through the inputs to the submit button and pressing enter the click event fires for me - just tried with the Onclick test case JSFiddle posted in my original question (Chrome/FF/IE11). Which browser did you use? Maybe you could do something like document.getElementById('your-input').onkeydown = function( e ) {
    if ( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
  targetElement.setCustomValidity("Your message");
    }
}

Comment: Final thought: you might try using e.preventDefault() on your onsubmit handler, before your setCustomValidity code — that's if you must use onsubmit.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a working jsfiddle base on your first example http://jsfiddle.net/bZe5e/6/.

The key is instead of doing this only on submit/button click. You are checking the validity on change + initially

```
doValidate();
```

Comment: Thanks :) Having the function run initially causes the validation check to occur before the user has even started filling out the form, which isn't desirable. In Firefox, this puts a red glow around the first checkbox. I guess I just want my custom validation to fire at the same time as HTML5 attribute validation (e.g. required, pattern, etc)

Comment: Actually this is how it works. A required and blank field is also invalid from the beginning. The fact that firefox renders the red outline/box-shadow is indeed annoying. see also here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=655677

Comment: Interesting. Your bug report explains Firefox's behaviour, which appears to be in contrast to other modern browsers. Thanks - you've provided a useful couple of replies.

Answer (score 4):

I came across a similar problem, and for me it worked calling
`reportValidity()` right after `setCustomValidity()`.

```
function onSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  const myInput = document.getElementById('my-input');

  if( inputIsInvalid ){
    myInput.setCustomValidity('My custom invalidity message.');
    myInput.reportValidity();
  }
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation#constraint_validation_process